# What's a good starting point for using Bluetooth input on mac in C?

Tags: c, macos, bluetooth

I want to use my PS3 controller (in wireless mode) as an input device for a C (note, not objective C) program on my mac. I got the controller to pair and I can get data from it with Apple's PacketLogger.app bluetooth utility... so I know the data is being sent (I can even press buttons and see it send different values), I just want to know how to get that data in my own programs.

I was expecting to be able to just open a bluetooth domain socket or something along those lines, but that appears not to be the case.

I found [this documentation from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html?filter=bluetooth) but A) its objective-c and B) it claims to be leopard only and snow leopard is the target platform.

Could somebody please point me in the direction of a good example/some good documentation on how to interact with a bluetooth device in C on a mac?

If I can't do it in C, my next step is to try [LightBlue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/).

Many thanks,

Comment: I believe you need to use Objective-C/Cocoa for Mac development...

Comment: I'd like to congratulate you on the thoroughness of only your second question :)

Comment: @tekknolagi: a full `gcc` is available, so C, C++ are easy; Ada and Fortran are probably not too hard either. Not to mention the _huge_ amount of scripting languages and boutique languages like Erlang, D, Go, etc...

Comment: @sarnold this is true, with XCode, but I meant for application development one needs to use Objective-C/Cocoa

Comment: @tekknolagi, well, if you want a _pretty_ gui, yes, that makes sense. :)

Comment: @sarnold fair point, though with Mac apps isn't that expected? :P

Comment: This is not for an "application", it is simply a test program for the command line to see if I can interface with bluetooth. In the end, this will probably be a daemon anyway, so GUIs don't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [ROS](http://www.ros.org) (Robot Operating System*) [OSX joystick package](https://github.com/walchko/osx_joystick) might be a good starting point, at least it sounds like they got the PS3 controller to work on OSX. While the (very small) package itself is in C++, the [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) library they use is in C.. Just ignore the ROS-ness like setting up publish/subscribe stuff, initialising nodes etc. ;-)

This is probably less useful for general purpose bluetooth communications, but from what I remember the PS3 controller was a bit "special" in terms of pairing etc anyway, so hopefully it will be useful anyway.

* it's more a "meta operating system" than a bare-metal OS like OSX, Windows & Linux.